# Storing iOS UI Component internal Usage Flags

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Most of the Apples implementation, I could see they use a struct to store the flag bit, why they are doing like that?. Why can't we use the BOOL to handle this instead?.

See the Apple's sample code below from tableview,

```
    struct {
           unsigned int delegateheightForHeaderInSection:1;
           unsigned int dataSourceCellForRow:1;
           unsigned int delegateHeightForRow:1;
           unsigned int style:1;
           } _tableFlags;
```

and internally they may be using them something similar to this,

```
  _tableFlags.delegateheightForHeaderInSection = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)];
```

use the "_tableFlags.delegateheightForHeaderInSection" everywhere to check the whether the user has implemented this delegate method.

So instead ofhaving the struct to store the flag, can't we implement like below.

```
 BOOL delegateheightForHeaderInSection;
```

use it like this,

```
 delegateheightForHeaderInSection = [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)];
```

What difference does this two approaches have?.

Comment: I think technically there's no big difference, It's just about wrapping up content for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int delegateheightForHeaderInSection:1;
```

defines a **bit field** of length 1 in the structure (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).
Bit fields can be used to save space. So in this case, the four members `delegateheightForHeaderInSection`, ..., `style` are stored in contiguous *bits* of one integer.

Note that no space is saved in this particular case. The size of `_tableFlags` is the size of `unsigned int`, which is 4. The size of four `BOOL` (aka `unsigned char`) members is also 4.

But for example, 32 bit fields of length 1 also take 4 bytes, whereas 32 `BOOL` members would take 32 bytes.